# How do Deleted Posts affect rep?

Tags: discussion, reputation, deleted-posts, fastest-gun

Say I post an answer on a recently asked question, yet a FGITW scenario means that so do about a half dozen other SO users. My answer might get a handful of upvotes, but ultimately someone else gets the green check. 
Since all of the answers are roughly saying the same thing, I go ahead and delete my answer since it's not really adding anything to the discussion (and the question's already been answered).
 My question is: what happens to the rep I got from my upvoted question? Do I still get awarded the points even though my answer no longer exists? Is this by design, or will I lose the points on a rep recalc? I'd rather have SO be less cluttered and am willing to delete redundant answers of mine; I'm just interested in the mechanics of how rep works in a situation like this.

Comment: I don't think it's clutter to be cleared, your post may propose roughly the same solution, but it won't be identical to others posted in most cases. The system handles having the best answers float to the top, so I'd rather see every answer left there - even ones that are downvoted, as they're a good example of what is not a good solution.

Comment: Is the answer still correct? I recall from a SE podcast deleted posts now don't affect rep under certain circumstances...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A recalc would remove rep from deleted content (answers, questions). Recalc's almost always result in reduced rep. I think there was someone recently that requested a recalc and he lost over 700 rep points. Someone back me up or correct me on that stat to confirm.

Comment: OK. That's what I thought; just wanted the clarification.

Comment: Yea; it was me. I requested a rep-recalc and due to the number of migrated questions / closed / deleted questions I participated in, there was a bit of a hit (almost 800 reputation). I expect when a system wide one is done it should bring everyone else where I am (more or less).

Answer (score 3):

It will exist until there is a global reputation recalculation (or a personal one, that you can ask any mod to do)

The global recalc does not happen very often

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question has changed due to technical improvements at the site.

You will lose your reputation already upon deleting the question.  Recalculation typically does not result in a reputation change anymore, unless there is a defect or a very special scenario involved.