# If I delete a question or answer of mine, how does it affect mine/others reputation?

Tags: support, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do Deleted Posts affect rep?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18308/how-do-deleted-posts-affect-rep)

If I delete a question or answer of mine, how does it affect mine/others reputation?

If I get down voted for a question, can I delete it and will it give me my rep back?
What about others who answered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an answer with positive rep that is later deleted (either your answer is or the question is) you will lose out on those points the next time there ever is a reputation recalc.

So if you have a question that gets deleted, everybody who scored up on that question will also lose their rep from answers posted to that.

Comment: Which is one reason why the asker can't delete a question which has an upvoted answer.