# Minimise reputation flux due to deleted posts

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, reputation

This proposal was partly discussed in this post: [how-do-deleted-posts-affect-rep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18308/how-do-deleted-posts-affect-rep), but the only solution to update the rep after a post is deleted seems to be a complete recalculation.

I am wondering whether this is technically necessary. I think it would be more convenient for users if they got a hint before deletion how many rep they'd lose from this post. If they choose to delete it the effect should be instant. I have worked on denormalization strategies myself and have never seen the need to do a complete recalculation if the denormalized data is updated correctly.

I think we should try to keep the currency "reputation" as solid as possible and avoid fluctuations altogether (besides rule changes, which I do strongly support).

Another part of the problem is how deleting posts with down-votes should work, I don't think reputation should be regained. If everything is only soft-deleted anyway this wouldn't cause any additional headaches during recalculations.

Comment: This is under way, see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/upcoming-reputation-history-changes

Comment: This is now rolled out on meta and soon the rest of the network, [you can read more about the reputation changes here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/upcoming-reputation-history-changes)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds good to me, but I think that reputation should be regained for deleted posts with downvotes - you were wrong, have (hopefully) realised your mistake, and have removed it. Shouldn't that behaviour be encouraged?

This might not be appropriate if *you* (the person who wrote the downvoted answer) didn't personally delete the question (e.g. a mod deleted it).

I'd agree more for things flagged offensive/spam, since you've presumably done something actively detrimental to the community.

Comment: My reading of "Questions and answers sometimes get deleted; votes on deleted posts do not count toward your reputation." (http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/03/the-great-reputation-recalc-begins/) is that deleted downvotes no longer count against you either (just like upvotes no longer help you), no matter who deletes the post.

Comment: @Gnome - yep, I'm just saying that should remain the case.

Answer (score 3):

The variable here is *hitting the rep-cap on a given day*.

If you hit the rep cap, the effects of deleting a post depend on timing, and have to be calculated by walking the entire vote history.

For example, deleting a post could mean you don't hit the cap on that day, whereas with the post, you do.

Comment: You make it sound like that walk is huge though -- but (when a user's post is deleted, or when a vote is retracted) it should only be necessary to revisit all votes made to that user's posts *for that one day*.

Comment: @Jeff: I agree with Ether on this topic. This operation shouldn't be all too expensive and could be easily handed of to a background job or whatever.