# Would there be a problem with letting users do their own rep recalculations via http://stackoverflow.com/users/reputation?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, reputation-recalc

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Self-instigated rep recalc](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14200/self-instigated-rep-recalc)
>   [Allow 10k users to recalculate their own rep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50560/allow-10k-users-to-recalculate-their-own-rep)

Now that we have the [rep report](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation) pages, what problems would arise if running the report also performed the recalculation on the live database (with a suitable warning/are you sure? message of course)?

Would there be an extra burden on the servers? I can't see it would be any more than at present with everyone trying the new feature out.

If this were the case and well publicised then there'd be less need for there to be a scheduled job running to do this for you.

I suppose what I'm trying to suggest here is that if rep were seen as a more fluid thing that did go down on a regular basis due to deleted posts then if there was another major change it would be seen as less of an issue that it has been (for some people at least) for the last couple of days.

Comment: I doubt they'll be adding it as a scheduled job...

Comment: @Downvoter - it has been suggested in the past that recalcs are run on a regular basis.

Comment: I'd rather cache the recalcs based on last time you request such a page.

Comment: @BalusC - well yes, it's this sort of thing that needs to be considered.

Answer (score 1):

Now you can flag one of your posts and request a recalc.

A moderator will gladly do it, I've asked them in the past and it took less than 2 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how much server load this would generate, but I would rather have rep-recalc be a scheduled thing. The perfect time for it is during the monthly (is it monthly?) maintenance downtime. That would recalc the rep and adjust for deleted/migrated posts etc.

Giving users an on-demand recalc option means the SO team needs to spend time coding preventative measures (time limits etc.) to prevent abuse. That might not be hard but opening it up means coding around these considerations. Making it a part of the system keeps this unexposed. I think it's better to flag a mod for an immediate request, otherwise have the system handle it in a scheduled manner.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you're asking. Performing a rep recalc by visiting the rep-report page?

How many users visit that page?

Aren't rep recalc's already being done?

Comment: 1) Yes - 2) It's brand new, he's saying it would be advertised as a feature - 3) no, it's been done once

Comment: Rep isn't recalculated automatically. Only by request or under special circumstances (like last night).

Comment: There's a global rep recalc due to the change in question up-vote scores, but normally recalcs don't happen unless a) a user requests it, b) there's been some suspicious voting going on, or c) some other reason I can't think of right now. Having a "recalc" button on your profile page would be the obvious way of linking to the page.

Comment: That clarified things, thanks. Now why do we need frequent rep-recalcs in the first place? Does it actually change something?

Comment: @Josh: you didn't notice a change to your rep? :) But seriously, one reason to do a recalc would be after this happened: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19920/how-does-the-so-voter-fraud-detection-mechanism-work

Comment: @Ether - recaclcs are run automatically after fraud has been detected and corrected.

Comment: @Ether: I noticed about a 100 rep drop at most. I'm not a big question man. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think we should eliminate the need for frequent rep-calcs altogether. Recalc is Ok in case of retroactive rule changes, but for everything else (esp. deletion) the effect should be instant.

If you think so too, please join the discussion [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43426/minimise-reputation-flux-due-to-deleted-posts) on meta.