# Make reputation recalcs unnecessary

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, reputation, reputation-recalc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Minimise Reputation Flux due to Deleted Posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43426/minimise-reputation-flux-due-to-deleted-posts)

I think your reputation should **never** be "desynched". In other words if after a rep recalc your reputation is not exactly the same I consider it a bug.

Therefore I propose to fix all the situations that make your reputation change after a recalc without actually modifying your current score.

I'll list the ones I'm aware of; feel free to add more (this is why this is CW):

- Your question is migrated (if that happens remove the reputation given from upvotes, and, if the user reached the cap, count the upvotes not previously counted because of the cap, if any). Do so for all the answers too.
- Your question/answer is deleted
- Your question/answer is undeleted

<sub>Note: obviously reputation recalcs will still be needed for changes like the decrease of rep for question upvotes.</sub>