# Should Reputation, Badges etc be Regularly Audited?

Tags: discussion, reputation

The reason I ask this is because I see when a question is migrated from one site to another, the reputation and badges earned from that question still remain on the original site.

Don't you think that to give user a more accurate view of his rep and badges, they must be constantly recalculated to take into consideration of current snapshot of the site?

Comment: see a **much** better solution: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43979/make-reputation-recalcs-unnecessary-closed

Comment: The post in Kop's comment is closed as a dupe of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43426/minimise-reputation-flux-due-to-deleted-posts