# Bad Post Mechanics: What happens, over time, when you post a bad answer on StackOverflow?

Tags: discussion, reputation, down-votes, deleted-answers

**Primary Question**

What happens, over time, when you post a bad answer on StackOverflow?

Assume someone posted a question that would accumulate:

- Two down votes per hour
- One up vote per hour
- One flag per day

Exactly how would that pan out, over time?

---

**Related Sub-Questions**

*Scoring*

- After an hour, your score is -2, then you get 1 upvote (for a score of -1), do you get +10 for that upvote?
- Instead, is your total rep score just:  (-2 * SCORE) when negative and (+10 * SCORE) when positive?
- You get the *Peer Pressure* badge for deleting your post when it has -3 votes. Is it a good practice to delete questions as soon as they get -2 votes?

*Deleting*

- What happens after you delete it, say once it's at -12?
- Do the -24 rep points get returned to you?
- Do you get any reputation points for deleting it?
- Or when you delete an answer is it as though it never happened?
- Once it's auto-deleted (for being flagged by 6 people), you lose 100 rep. Is this in addition to the rep you lost for the downvotes?  So would an auto-deleted post with a -12 score yeild a loss of -124 rep?

---

**Background**

Recently, I [answered a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3689921/when-i-submit-my-app-to-the-apple-app-store-do-they-see-my-source-code) and included a lighthearted joke that took a shot at Apple. Instantly, it received down votes, accumulating a total score around -12 in 48 hours.  This really surprised me so I just watched it, fascinated at how it all worked.

After a while, a more experienced user recommended that I delete the question stating that it currently had two flags and if it got 4 more, then it would be automatically deleted and I would lose 100 reputation!

So I deleted the post.  This earned me the *Peer Pressure* badge and removed all references to the question from my *profile/controlPanel* area.  In fact, I had to do a search just to find the question again because all references in my profile to activity involving that question were gone.  When I visited https://stackoverflow.com/reputation, I couldn't see any information about losing rep.  However, my rep score seemed to still reflect -24 points. It's hard to tell exactly what happened. So I figured I'd ask here, what happens over time as a bad answer get's down voted and flagged and ultimately deleted?

Comment: You're going to get back your reputation, but only when its getting recalculated, which might take a long time.

Comment: Comments work better for [non-serious/jokes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3689921/when-i-submit-my-app-to-the-apple-app-store-do-they-see-my-source-code/3689927#3689927), rather than answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Votes on deleted posts affect rep until your next reputation recalculates — which you can request from a moderator by flagging one of your own posts and asking nicely.  You can preview what the recalculated rep will be through /reputation, as you saw.  (So there's not much point if it's close to what you have now.)

**Balance**

There is something of a limit to rep loss for a bad question/answer merely because people hesitate to vote down most negative posts.  In fact, given the disparity of reputation (+5/10 for upvote, -2 for downvote), a highly negative answer can still be a net rep gain!

**Flagging Behavior**

Flagging is different, and you do lose 100 rep (for non-CW posts only). That requires 6 flags within 2 days.  These posts are then deleted similarly to when you self-delete.  However, they are also locked to prevent undelete votes (from 10k+ users).

Answer (score 3):

- You would gain 6 rep per hour. The effect of flagging [depends on the type of flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22174/how-does-the-offensive-flag-work/22175#22175).
- You lose the rep, but not
  permenantly. You can get it back by flagging one of your posts for moderator attention
  and asking for a rep recalc (as Diago said) ([see this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18308/how-do-deleted-posts-affect-rep)).
- Votes still have the same values no matter what the score of the post is ([see this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1390/should-we-reduce-rep-bonus-for-upvotes-on-posts-with-a-negative-score)).

Comment: You don't need to email the team for a reputation recalc. Any moderator can do it if  you flag a post and ask.