# If I delete my own answer, will I lose reputation?

Tags: support, reputation, deleted-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that-actually-mean)
>   [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)
>   [How do Deleted Posts affect rep?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18308/how-do-deleted-posts-affect-rep)

I have been wondering, if I delete my **own answer or question**, will I *lose reputation* since it is being deleted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you had gained or lost rep on a question or answer and then you delete it, nothing will change until your reputation is recalculated.  Then it will be like the question or answer never existed.

You can do your own reputation recalc by going to `/reputation` for your site.

Comment: Thanks, but I meant if it was an answer with no down votes and no up votes. Would I still loose reputation?

Comment: No, no votes, no rep.  But if you do it a whole bunch, then you might trigger the posting ban.

Comment: Okay, thanks! I wont delete that much - I just wanted to make sure.

Comment: @Nathan: The only thing you have to watch out for is that you don't delete a whole bunch of your questions within a short period of time. Deleting a couple of questions, though, will not cost you any reputation (as Lance already pointed out).

Comment: I had posted an answer, but I removed as it was not the relevant and had no point leaving it there when I understood the quetion needs answers with better calibration. So I removed the answer. And it had no downvotes. Then I noticed -6 reputatinos has gone out of my rep total. So just wondering what just happened...

Comment: @bonCodigo, check your reputation summary in your user profile, it usually gives all the details.

Comment: Thanks Lance. But this -6 is no where to be found. But anyway I am not worried. I would worry if it was anything above 10 ;)

Comment: I wrote an answer I want to delete, but it gave me enough rep to vote up the better answer. If I delete, does she lose that vote?