# Which Stackexchange Site Gets The Rep?

Tags: support, migration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do migrated questions migrate reputation and badges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6378/do-migrated-questions-migrate-reputation-and-badges)

Let's say I post a question about [Game Development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) and I (accidentally or otherwise) post it on *Stackoverflow*. I get answers,  the answers get upvoted. Then some Moderator moves (migrates?) the question to the [gamedev site](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) , where it actually belongs.

Now should the reputation I and others have earned (or lost) by the question through votes on answers, votes on the question, edits etc. also be moved to their gamedev accounts or stay in their SO accounts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  But it won't happen right away.  From time to time a reputation re-calc is performed to go back and set right what once went wrong.  It's a fairly heavy process, so it doesn't happen all the time.

More info [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18308/how-do-deleted-posts-affect-rep), among others.

I've lost upwards of a couple hundred points on a re-calc before when some of my answers were migrated to Programmers.  (It was kind of funny... I had just reached 10k, then the re-calc bumped me back down and I had to reach it again.)

So basically your current rep is denormalized from what gave you the rep, for performance reasons.  And every once in a blue moon a back-end process will re-calculate it as a sanity check.

Comment: It is possible to recalculate the reputation visiting http://stackoverflow.com/reputation, and clicking on the button at the end ("Trigger Reputation Recalc"). I would not suggest doing it every day (the actual limit for triggering a recalc), but rather when it is really necessary.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: Indeed.  I'd seen that before, but I wasn't sure how much I should advertise it :)