# Question got deleted for reasons of moderation & lost rep gained?

Tags: discussion, reputation

The question I answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16379309/syntax-error-unexpected-t-variable-in-scripts-login-scripts-php-on-line-7/16379316#16379316

Got closed, but I still had an active answer.. Me being nice, I carried on the assistance; but I have just discovered the question to be deleted:

> This question was removed from Stack Overflow for reasons of
>   moderation

Why did I lose the reputation gained from my answer because of this deletion?

Comment: [meta-tag:status-bydesign]

Comment: Once it's deleted, it's as if it never existed. (unless it falls into a number of exceptions)

Comment: @ColeJohnson Care to explain?

Comment: Duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18308/212576

Comment: I understand the moderation teams decision.. But the question was removed sometime after the question got closed.. That I can't understand why.

Comment: @DarylGill I believe you shouldn't even put effort in answering topics covered by [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12769982/1331430), the PHP cv-ring is rather strict closing and deleting such questions.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté That may be your outlook on that.. But if someone has come to Stack overflow.. i see no problem one bit with assisting them, regardless of their question.. No disrespect, but i'm not as quick to judge

Comment: @DarylGill Correct, helping is our aim. Though, code-dump questions with (close to) no research effort which serve for no future reference tend to end up being closed/deleted. Even more when it is about basic syntax errors such as unexpected T_XXX. I'm just saying so you're prepared for the next time this happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a question is deleted, it's as if it never existed in the first place.

Thus, *everyone* who had a reputation change from that question will have the change neutralized upon deletion.

Comment: As an interesting side note, any badges won off the deleted question persist.